# Не выводится значение переменной считанной с файла. Как можно исправить?

Tags: python, tkinter

Суть такова: пишу мини программу, которая должна проверять правильность введённого пароля. Сам пароль содержится в файле. Проблема в том, что когда я сравниваю значение введённого в Entry и значение переменной, которая хранит данные считанные с файла, программа как будто бы не видит значение считанного файла при сравнении. Как можно исправить?
Чуть не забыл, пароль в текстовом файле выглядит так: `22fFЖж,,`

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import hashlib

root = Tk()
root.title('main')
root.geometry('400x400')

c = Canvas(width=400, height = 400, bg='gray')
c.place(x=0,y=0)

l1 = Label(text = '1', font = 'TimesNewRoman 24', bg = 'green')
l1.place(x=100,y=100)

l2 = Label(text = 'Введите пароль:', font = 'TimesNewRoman 24', bg = 'green')
l2.place(x=75,y=200)

e1 = Entry(width = 25)
e1.place(x=125,y=250)

btn1 = Button(text ="Проверить пароль", command = lambda:sravnenie())
btn1.place(x=140, y=280)

file1 = open("simple.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8')
global line
while True:
    # считываем строку
    line = file1.read()
    # прерываем цикл, если строка пустая
    if not line:
        break
    #print(line)

k = 0
def sravnenie():
    global k
    
    a = e1.get()
    print(a)
    print(line)
    if a == str(line):
        print('Пароль верный!')
        l3 = Label(text = 'Успех!',borderwidth = 5)
        l3.place(x=120, y=50)
        
    else:
        l4 = Label(text = 'Неверный пароль!')
        l4.place(x=120, y=50)
        k += 1
        print(k)
        if k >= 3:
            print(k,"Достигнут лимит!")


def develop():
    l1.config(text = '1')
    c.after(2000, configure1)
    

def configure1():
    l1.config(text = '2')
    c.after(2000, configure2)

def configure2():
    l1.config(text = '3')
    c.after(2000, develop)
    



develop()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: как вы определили что "как будто не видит"?

Comment: В функции `def sravnenie`, я пытался вывести в принте значение энтри и с файла, выводилось только с энтри, а с файла была пустая строка.

Comment: ну так посмотрите на свой код - вы же читаете файл до тех пор, пока не считается пустая строка. В итоге в переменной и лежит пустая строка

Comment: Да, но когда я вывожу значение line в цикле while, оно всё выводит верно.

Comment: Все правильно. Только после того, как выводит значение, цикл еще не закончился, а продолжается. Зачем вы вообще читаете в цикле?

Comment: Спасибо, понял в чём ошибка, всё работает теперь. Этот цикл там вообще не нужен.